# Git list merged/unmerged tags

Tags: git

With 3 primary development branches:

```
patch
minor
major
```

When we create a patch release tag from the `patch` branch:

```
git tag -a my-project-1.2.3 -m "This is the 1.2.3 patch release of My Project"
```

We then want to port those changes forward. For example, into the `1.3.0` minor development branch:

```
git checkout minor
git merge my-project-1.2.3
```

And into the 'very future' `2.0.0` major development branch:

```
git checkout major
git merge my-project-1.2.3
```

But... **What happens** if we have performed the merge only on `minor`, and forgot to merge it into `major`? If it were a branch, we could run:

```
git branch --no-merged major
```

Which would list the branch. But, **tags are not included** in this list. How can I determine whether a tag has been merged into a branch, or list tags that have not been merged into a specific branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it the other way around:

```
git branch --contains **tag**
```

lists all the branches into which `tag` was merged.